# how to call method on query result in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

how to call method on  query result  in Rails 
i have following code in my projects controller

def inprogress_report
@projects = Project.all

@project_list =  Project.find_by_sql("select p.id, p.name, (select sum(i.estimated_hours) from issues i where  i.project_id = p.id)  as estimated_hours,(select sum(t.hours)  from time_entries t where p.id = t.project_id )  as Spent_Hours,(select u.firstname  from users u  where u.id IN(select user_id from members m where m.project_id = p.id and m.id IN   ( select member_id from member_roles   where role_id IN (select id from roles r where r.name  = 'Project Coordinator') )) limit 1 ) as Coordinator,(select u.firstname  from users u  where u.id IN(select user_id from members m where m.project_id = p.id and m.id IN   ( select member_id from member_roles   where role_id IN (select id from roles r where r.name  = 'Project Manager') )) limit 1) as  Manager   from projects p where p.status IN ('16','14','15','17','18','19','20')   group by p.id")

Now i want to make serch on  @project_list result

so i have put

```
@project_list = @project_list.search(params[:search])
```

and in my project.rb there is

```
def search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

but gives me error undefined search method...

Can i use Active Record::Base.connection.select_all for above query and in a result i want further sorting is that possible plz guide me

Comment: `search` is undefined for `project_list`, it would only be defined for your model. `find_by_sql` returns an `array`.

Comment: Can i use Active Record::Base.connection.select_all for above query and in a result i want further sorting is that possible plz guide me

Answer (score 0):

find_by_sql returns a plain array, not a result set. You have to build up your query without find_by_sql if you want to add additional conditions to it.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class

Answer (score 0):

Maximilian Gaß is right, but since it might take a while to rewrite the `find_by_sql` method call, I would rewrite the `search` method call to use the array returned by the `find_by_sql` method call if the size of the result array is reasonable. In other words, instead of:

```
@project_list = @project_list.search(params[:search])
```

put something like:

```
@project_list.keep_if{ |p| /.*#{params[:search]}.*/.match p.name }
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error? That sounds like @project_list is nil.

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `keep_if' for #<Class:0xb6194450>):
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:90:in `report'